# I need to search data in account records for oerticular field

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

Requirement:-  In account object i have one field with name approve_Profile__c.

i have 1Lakh of account records.  I need to check for this(approve_Profile__c) field  for data.

```
Select id,approve_Profile__c from account where approve_Profile__c like 
'%system administartor%' or approve_Profile__c like '%standard user%' or 
approve_Profile__c like '%chatter user%'
```

But i have 261 profiles with me ,So instead of writing field name and like operator every time ,is there any other way to search profile names in account records

Comment: What is Data Type of field `approve_Profile__c`? text or lookup? Which profiles you want to check all? few? please elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: Data type is -Text and I need to check all profiles one by one or in one shot.Please share if you have any solution please.

Comment: You can query it by filtering in where clause e.g. `Where approve_Profile__c != null`.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that you want to query every account that has a value in approve profile then i would use.
`Select id,approve_Profile__c from account where approve_Profile__c != ''`

this query will return you all the accounts where approve_Profile__c is not empty. This will work as long as the only value in this field is 1 of your 261 profiles